# Raster reprojection to latlon changes values

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster, map-projections

I start with the following Raster:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 900, 900, 810000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 2500  (min, max)
```

If i reproject this raster to latlon with:

```
  raster_projection <- projectRaster(rb, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
```

it creates a reprojection with significant shift in data:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 944, 1014, 957216  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0136, 0.00857  (x, y)
extent     : 2.00348, 15.79388, 46.99609, 55.08617  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -0.6159579, 3583.708  (min, max)
```

I think the data points are so to say: "too far up".

Is this to be expected?

How can i create a reprojection that is more true to original ?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check where these points with values outside the original value range are? The reprojected raster probably covers larger area than the original one and I would guess that in these new areas, where values have to be extrapolated, the bilinear interpolation used by `projectRaster` may produce some weird values.

Comment: good point. I have to check.

Comment: I think method="ngb" eliminates the problem with values. The shift i think stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new extreme values are likely at the edges; and so your problem may be caused by a few cells. A more appropriate comparison could be to look at a boxplot or quantiles. You could also use `terra::project` instead. I think that method is less prone to this.